# append and remove div with unique ID on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, append

I am currently working on a web app on www.firstusadata.com/cash_flow_test/ 
The two buttons currently add a products div and vendors div, which is working, however when these new divs are appended, they do not have a unique ID and I am unable to remove the appended divs.

My current jquery function for the two buttons look like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".addproduct",function(){
        $("#dynamic_content_2").append(dynamic_html1());
    });

    $(document).on("click",".removeproduct",function(){
        var check = 0;
        $(".dynamic_content_2").each(function(){
            check++;
        });
        if(check>0){
            $(this).parents(".dynamic_content_2").remove();
        }
    });


    $(document).on("click",".addvendor",function(){
        $("#dynamic_content_1").append(dynamic_html2());
    });

    $(document).on("click",".removevendor",function(){
        var check = 0;
        $(".dynamic_content_1").each(function(){
            check++;
        });
        if(check>0){
            $(this).parents(".dynamic_content_1").remove();
        }
    });
```

The full code is available below on the "show code snippet" as well as on jsfiddle via this link https://jsfiddle.net/8eanq9tv/   I hope someone is able to help me resolve this issue. This community has taken the time to help me before. Thank you!

```js
function dynamic_html1(){
   var content = '<div id="dynamic_content_1">'
   +'<div class="row">'
      +'<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">'
       +'<div class="form-group w100">'
        +'<input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product" required >'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
       +'<div class="form-group  w100">'
        +'<input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price" required >'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
       +'<select class="form-control w100" id="" name="product_type[]" required >'
        +'<option value="">Select</option>'
        +'<option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>'
        +'<option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>'
       +'</select>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
       +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
        +'<button type="button" class="btn addproduct btn-default pull-left">'
         +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
        +'</button>'
        
        +'<button type="button" class="btn removeproduct btn-default pull-left">'
         +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
        +'</button>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>';
   return content;
  }
  
  

  
  
  
  function dynamic_html2(){
   var content =  '<div id="dynamic_content_2">'                    
  +'<div class="row">'
   +'<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 SecPageMain">'
               +'<h3>Vendor Information</h3>'
    +'<form method="post" action="http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow/companies/insert_company_information">'
     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Name of Company:</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" name="company_name" required="" >'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'

     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Company Phone Number:</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="" name="company_phone" required="" >'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'

     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Did this company build your website?</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">'
       +'<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" >'
        +'<input type="radio"  value="1" name="built_website">'
        +'<label for="inlineRadio1"> Yes </label>'
       +'</div>'
       +'<div class="radio radio-inline">'
        +'<input type="radio"  value="0" name="built_website" checked>'
        +'<label for="inlineRadio2"> No </label>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     
     +'<div class="hide" id="BuildWebsite" >'
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Website URL:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="website_url" name="website_url">'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Type of Website:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" id="type_of_website" name="type_of_website">'
         +'<option value="Amazon Store">Amazon Store</option>'
         +'<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>'
         +'<option value="Drop Ship">Drop Ship</option>'
         +'<option value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</option>'
         +'<option value="Small Business">Small Business</option>'
         +'<option value="Landing Page">Landing Page</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10 category_area" style="display:none">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Category:</p>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" id="website_category" name="website_category">'
         +'<option value="">Select category</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Average Profit Margin Per 100 Users:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +' <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100 price" id="average_profit" name="average_profit">'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     
     +'<div id="dynamic_content_2">'
      +'<div class="row margin_top_25 form-inline product_row">'
       +'<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">'
        +'<div class="form-group w100">'
         +'<input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product"  required>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
        +'<div class="form-group  w100">'
         +'<input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price"  required>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" name="product_type[]" required>'
         +'<option value="">Select</option>'
         +'<option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>'
         +'<option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
         +'<button type="button" class="btn addproduct btn-default pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
         
         +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeproduct pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
        +'</div>' 
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
                    
                    
           +'<h4>Add Vendor</h4>'         
            +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
         +'<button type="button" class="btn addvendor btn-default pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
         
         +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removevendor pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'                 
    +'</form>'
   +'</div>'
  +'</div>'
       +' </div>';
   return content;
  }           



















$(document).on("click",".addproduct",function(){
   $("#dynamic_content_2").append(dynamic_html1());
  });
  
  $(document).on("click",".removeproduct",function(){
   var check = 0;
   $(".dynamic_content_2").each(function(){
    check++;
   });
   if(check>0){
    $(this).parents(".dynamic_content_2").remove();
   }
  });
  

  $(document).on("click",".addvendor",function(){
   $("#dynamic_content_1").append(dynamic_html2());
  });
  
  $(document).on("click",".removevendor",function(){
   var check = 0;
   $(".dynamic_content_1").each(function(){
    check++;
   });
   if(check>0){
    $(this).parents(".dynamic_content_1").remove();
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="dynamic_content_1">                     
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 SecPageMain">
               <h3>Vendor Information</h3>
    <form method="post" action="http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow/companies/insert_company_information">
     <div class="row margin_top_25">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
       <p>Name of Company:</p>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" name="company_name" required='' >
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row margin_top_25">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
       <p>Company Phone Number:</p>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="" name="company_phone" required='' >
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row margin_top_25">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
       <p>Did this company build your website?</p>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
       <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" >
        <input type="radio"  value="1" name="built_website">
        <label for="inlineRadio1"> Yes </label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio radio-inline">
        <input type="radio"  value="0" name="built_website" checked>
        <label for="inlineRadio2"> No </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="hide" id="BuildWebsite" >
      <div class="row margin_top_10">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Website URL:</p>
       </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="website_url" name="website_url">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row margin_top_10">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Type of Website:</p>
       </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control w100" id="type_of_website" name="type_of_website">
         <option value="Amazon Store">Amazon Store</option>
         <option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>
         <option value="Drop Ship">Drop Ship</option>
         <option value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</option>
         <option value="Small Business">Small Business</option>
         <option value="Landing Page">Landing Page</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row margin_top_10 category_area" style="display:none">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Category:</p>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control w100" id="website_category" name="website_category">
         <option value="">Select category</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row margin_top_10">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Average Profit Margin Per 100 Users:</p>
       </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100 price" id="average_profit" name="average_profit">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="dynamic_content_2">
      <div class="row margin_top_25 form-inline product_row">
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group w100">
         <input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product"  required>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group  w100">
         <input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price"  required>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control w100" name="product_type[]" required>
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>
         <option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>
        </select>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">
         <button type="button" class="btn addproduct btn-default pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
         
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeproduct pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
         </button>
        </div> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
                    
                    
           <h4>Add Vendor</h4>          
             <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">
         <button type="button" class="btn addvendor btn-default pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
         
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removevendor pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
         </button>
        </div> 
       </div>          
                    
                    
                    
                    
     
     <div class="row margin_top_25 margin_bottom_25"> 
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                          <div class="btn-inline">
         
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Summary</button>
               </div> 
      </div> 
     </div>

    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `dynamic_content_2` is your `ID` and not `class`

```
$(".dynamic_content_2").each(function(){
            check++;
        });
```

It should be like `$("#dynamic_content_2").each(`

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8eanq9tv/1/)

> Plus you should know that `ID` should be unique always. You should use
>   `class` rather.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the append and remove issue that I was having. But I am still wondering how I can add unique ID's to these divs because when I click the (-) button it removes all appended divs since they have the same ID.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on proper ID and Class use.  I have changed the <div id="dynamic_content_1"> to <div class="dynamic_content_1"> and reverted the changes I made previously to the function. It is working as it should by adding and removing the divs, but since they still have the same ID it removes all of them. How can I add unique ID's to these appended elements? Here is the updated jsfiddle with the changes you suggested https://jsfiddle.net/2zq10v8r/

Comment: checout the DOM positions poperly.. you are not appending the html at right place ...inspect the elements properly.....and append at the right place.... and it will work

Comment: Any suggestions as to where I should be appending these elements? I have tried several locations and it is still not working.

Comment: @PaulCunningham  : see for first one i made it work https://jsfiddle.net/2zq10v8r/1/

Comment: @PaulCunningham : great !! you can click on tick mark and select it as answer